# Removing this kind of frame inside the text

Tags: python, tkinter

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Shop")


root.geometry("500x500")


root['background'] = '#fbf5df'

label = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to Our Shop! ", font=('Satoshi', 15), )
label.pack(padx = 20,pady = 20)



root.mainloop()
```

and here's how it looks like when executed:

[image]

I would like to remove the white spaces.

I am still new to the tkinter interface. I haven't tried anything yet. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can set background color for your label same as your actual background color: `bg='#fbf5df'`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Shop")
root.geometry("500x500")
root['background'] = '#fbf5df'
label = tk.Label(root, text="Welcome to Our Shop! ", font=('Satoshi', 15),  bg='#fbf5df')
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]